# Pandas dataframe column containing list, Get intersection of two consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe:

```
timestmp              coulmnis                                                
2015-10-15 18:24:00  set([a,b,c,d,e,f])
2015-10-15 18:27:00  set([a,b,g,h,i])
2015-10-15 18:30:00  set([g,h,j,k,l])
2015-10-15 18:33:00  set([a,b,g,h,j,k,l])
2015-10-15 18:36:00  set([d,e,j,k])
```

I want to check how many elemnets in a row is same as previous row.My output should look like this:

```
timestmp              coulmnis                   count_sameAsPrevious                          
2015-10-15 18:24:00  set([a,b,c,d,e,f])          0
2015-10-15 18:27:00  set([a,b,g,h,i])            2
2015-10-15 18:30:00  set([g,h,j,k,l])            2
2015-10-15 18:33:00  set([a,b,g,h,j,k,l])        5
2015-10-15 18:36:00  set([d,e,j,k])              2
```

What is the most efficient way so that I can avoid a for loop.Any help appreciated!!

EDIT:

```
df['shiftedColumn'] = df.columnis.shift(1)
df = df.dropna()
```

Now I want to use `len(filter(y.__contains__,x))` to get no of same elements  in two columns which contains `set`.

Comment: Is the `timestamp` the index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using [`DataFrame.shift()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to shift the rows by one column and then rename the `coulmnis` column to something else, then reset index and merge the dataframes on `timestmp` and then use `apply()` on the DataFrame. Example (in one line) -

```
df['count'] = df.reset_index().merge(df.shift(1).reset_index().rename(columns={'coulmnis':'newcol'})) \
                .set_index('timestmp').apply((lambda x: len(x['coulmnis'] & x['newcol']) if pd.notnull(x['newcol']) else 0),axis=1)
```

Example in a more readable way -

```
mergedf = df.shift(1).reset_index().rename(columns={'coulmnis':'newcol'})
newdf = df.merge(mergedf).set_index('timestmp')
df['count'] = newdf.apply((lambda x: len(x['coulmnis'] & x['newcol']) if pd.notnull(x['newcol']) else 0),axis=1)
```

---

Demo -

```
In [36]: df
Out[36]:
                                       coulmnis
timestmp
2015-10-15 18:24:00     set([f, b, c, e, d, a])
2015-10-15 18:27:00        set([g, b, i, a, h])
2015-10-15 18:30:00        set([l, g, k, j, h])
2015-10-15 18:33:00  set([b, j, h, k, a, l, g])
2015-10-15 18:36:00           set([d, e, k, j])

In [38]: df['count'] = df.reset_index().merge(df.shift(1).reset_index().rename(columns={'coulmnis':'newcol'})) \
   ....:                 .set_index('timestmp').apply((lambda x: len(x['coulmnis'] & x['newcol']) if pd.notnull(x['newcol']) else 0),axis=1)

In [39]: df
Out[39]:
                                       coulmnis  count
timestmp
2015-10-15 18:24:00     set([f, b, c, e, d, a])      0
2015-10-15 18:27:00        set([g, b, i, a, h])      2
2015-10-15 18:30:00        set([l, g, k, j, h])      2
2015-10-15 18:33:00  set([b, j, h, k, a, l, g])      5
2015-10-15 18:36:00           set([d, e, k, j])      2
```

Comment: HI can you explain len(x['coulmnis'] & x['newcol']) part??

Comment: It is taking intersection of the set in `coulmnis` and set in `newcol` for each row and then its length (set in `newcol` is the set from next row).

Comment: Earlier I was trying len(filter(y.__contains__,x)) for the same purpose but was not able to apply it on df

Comment: For `.apply` it would become - `len(filter(x['newcol'].__contains__,x['coulmnis']))` . But set intersection would be much faster than this.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'sets': [set(['a','b','c','d','e','f']), set(['a','b','g','h','i']), set(['g','h','j','k','l']), set(['a','b','g','h','j','k','l'])]})
df['sets_temp'] = pandas.Series([])
df['sets_temp'][1:] = df['sets'][:-1]
df['count'] = pandas.Series([])
df['count'][1:] = df[1:].apply(lambda row: len(row['sets'] & row['sets_temp']), axis=1)
df['count'][:1] = 0
df = df.drop('sets_temp', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                         sets  count
0     set([b, c, d, e, a, f])      0
1        set([b, h, i, a, g])      2
2        set([j, h, l, k, g])      2
3  set([j, b, h, k, l, a, g])      5
```

Actually `apply()` function is a wrapper on `for loop`, so the efficience of `apply()` is the same, but it looks like there is no chance to escape of using for loop-like method.

Comment: You have taken the difference from the first row only.I want no of same elements in consecutive rows